# How to use evince with emacs when writing Latex? D-Bus error: "disconnected from message bus without replying"

Tags: emacs, latex, documentviewer, i3

I can write Latex code in Emacs properly. When I press `C-c C-c`, the *pdf* is produced like it should:

> `LaTeX: successlully formatted {x} page[s]`.

After pressing `C-c C-c` again as usual, I get the following prompt in the *echo-area*:

`View command: TeX-evince-sync-view`. Again.. As expected! However, when pressing `RET`, I get the following error message:

```
> D-Bus error: "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply", "Message recipient
> disconnected from message bus without replying".
```

Side notes that are important:
I have a fresh arch linux installation with i3, I downloaded the full `tex live distribution` and added it to the *search paths*. Any help is welcome.